# I just want to change value if condition is true , else want to keep the previous value retained

Tags: r

ge[image]

I just want to fill the blank with "FINE" and rest all remains same

So, output should look like

```
OTHER  MINISTRIES
PRIVATE SECT
SEMI GOVT
RETIRED
RETIRED
FINE
..
```

..

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 df$EMPL_CATEGORY[df$EMPL_CATEGORY==''] <- 'FINE'
```

If it is `NA` for the missing values

```
 df$EMPL_CATEGORY[is.na(df$EMPL_CATEGORY)] <- 'FINE'
```